Saving a QImage sequence as video in QT C++
Is there a way to save a sequence of QImages as video in QT C++?
In fact I am trying to grab frames from camera, add some overlay and then save as video. The tricky part is that QMediaRecorder does not provide any direct functionality for this purpose, unlike MediaRecorder in OpenCV for example.

https://forum.qt.io/topic/87506/creating-a-video-file-in-qt

Please do not create new questions that are almost identical to those you already posted. You should instead consider to edit your existing question, providing more details and possible attempts in what you're doing. Knowing more about your env would obviously help, especially considering that the QtMultimedia module has changed a lot in the last years (and is still evolving). In any case, you should probably rely on dedicated encoders (possibly ffmpeg, which is also what Qt already uses since 6.5).

The question may be too broad to be eligible on this platform.
My advice would be: Always refer to the documentation, it provides almost all the information you need. Qt documentation also often provides examples to better illustrate how things are meant to be used.
For instance, from the QMediaRecorder page:

"The QMediaRecorder class is a high level media recording class. It's not intended to be used alone but for accessing the media recording functions of other media objects, like QRadioTuner, or QCamera."

You can even find a small example below that quote.
